# How to test equality of variables that contain dollar sign and possibly other symbols?

Tags: bash, jq

mwe.json

```
[
{ "eq": "$a=b^2" },
{ "eq": "$a=b**2" }
]
```

mwe.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

eq1=$( jq -r '.[0].eq' mwe.json )
eq2=$( jq -r '.[1].eq' mwe.json )
if [[ "$eq1" -eq "$eq2" ]]; then 
  echo "same TeX equation"
fi
```

error

```
$./mwe.sh
./mwe.sh: line 5: [[: $a=b^2: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "$a=b^2")
```

mwe2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

eq1=$( jq -r '.[0].eq' mwe.json )
eq2=$( jq -r '.[1].eq' mwe.json )
if [[ "'""$eq1""'" -eq "'""$eq2""'" ]]; then 
  echo "same equation"
fi
```

error

```
$./mwe2.sh
./mwe2.sh: line 5: [[: '$a=b^2': syntax error: operand expected (error token is "'$a=b^2'")
```

Could you suggest how to compare the two variables that contain dollar sign and other special symbols ?

Comment: Use == instead of -eq. -eq is for arithmetic comparison

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks ! Your suggestion works !

Comment: See: `help -m test | less`

Comment: @Cyrus That's very helpful ! Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to invoke jq twice:

```
#!/bin/bash
function data {
    cat<<EOF
[
  { "eq": "$a=b^2" },
  { "eq": "$a=b**2" }
]
EOF
}

data | jq '.[0].eq == .[0].eq'
data | jq '.[0].eq == .[1].eq'
echo Using -e:
data | jq -e '.[0].eq == .[0].eq' > /dev/null
echo $?
data | jq -e '.[0].eq == .[1].eq' > /dev/null
echo $?
```

yields:

```
true
false
Using -e:
0
1
```

Comment: TIL about jq `-e / --exit-status` option.  From the [docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) Sets the exit status of jq to 0 if the last output values was neither false nor null, 1 if the last output value was either false or null, or 4 if no valid result was ever produced. Normally jq exits with 2 if there was any usage problem or system error, 3 if there was a jq program compile error, or 0 if the jq program ran.